# Find unbounded file paths in string

Tags: c#, parsing

I have these error messages generated by a closed source third party software from which I need to extract file paths.

The said file paths are :

- not bounded (i.e. not surrounded by quotation marks, parentheses, brackets, etc)
- rooted (i.e. start with `<letter>:\` such as `C:\`)
- not guaranteed to have a file extension
- representing files (only files, not directories) that are guaranteed to exist on the computer running the extraction code.
- made of any valid characters, including spaces, making them hard to spot (e.g. `C:\This\is a\path \but what is an existing file path here`)

To be noted, there can be 0 or more file paths per message.

How can these file paths be found in the error messages?

I've suggested an answer below, but I have a feeling that there is a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each match, look forward for the next '\' character. So you might get "c:\mydir\". Check to see if that directory exists. Then find the next `\`, giving "c:\mydir\subdir`. Check for that path. Eventually you'll find a path that doesn't exist, or you'll get to the start of the next match.

At that point, you know what directory to look in. Then just call `Directory.GetFiles` and match the longest filename that matches the substring starting at the last path you found.

That should minimize backtracking.

Here's how this could be done:

```
static void FindFilenamesInMessage(string message) {
    // Find all the "letter colon backslash", indicating filenames.
    var matches = Regex.Matches(message, @"\w:\\", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    // Go backwards. Useful if you need to replace stuff in the message
    foreach (var idx in matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.idx).Reverse()) {
        int length = 3;
        var potentialPath = message.Substring(idx, length);
        var lastGoodPath = potentialPath;

        // Eat "\" until we get an invalid path
        while (Directory.Exists(potentialPath)) {
            lastGoodPath = potentialPath;
            while (idx+length < message.Length && message[idx+length] != '\\')
                length++;

            length++; // Include the trailing backslash

            if (idx + length >= message.Length)
                length = (message.Length - idx) - 1;

            potentialPath = message.Substring(idx, length);
        }

        potentialPath = message.Substring(idx);

        // Iterate over the files in directory we found until we get a match
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(lastGoodPath)
                                      .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)) {
            if (!potentialPath.StartsWith(file))
                continue;

            // 'file' contains a valid file name
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds sensible! :-) I'll give that a try later today and let you know how it fares.

Comment: It is indeed quite faster! On a run of 55K messages, my solution averages about 50 seconds while yours averages roughly 9 seconds! Mind if I edit your post with my implementation of your solution?

Comment: @Joce: Thanks for the update. You might be able to save a little more time by only checking files that start with the next character in the message. Something like `Directory.EnumerateFiles(lastGoodPath + "\" + message[idx+length] + "*")`

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't make a significant difference. Actually, if anything, it appears to be a tad slower than the version I posted. :-|

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

I don't think substringing the message over and over is a good idea however.

```cs
static void FindFilenamesInMessage(string message)
{
    // Find all the "letter colon backslash", indicating filenames.
    var matches = Regex.Matches(message, @"\w:\\", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    int length = message.Length;
    foreach (var index in matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Index).Reverse())
    {
        length = length - index;
        while (length > 0)
        {
            var subString = message.Substring(index, length);
            if (File.Exists(subString))
            {
                // subString contains a valid file name

                ///////////////////////
                // Payload goes here
                //////////////////////

                length = index;
                break;
            }
            length--;
        }
    }
}
```